# How can I add image on the tool-tip within SVG?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, src

Trying to reference image on a tooltip within an SVG map. The reference is as the following:

```
<path
 inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
 id="BD"
 data-info="<div>Bangladesh</div><div><img src="http://www.digi4health.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/bd.png" alt="Bangladesh mHealth" width="600" height="171"></div><div>Some Description</div>"
 data-name="Bangladesh"
 data-id="BD"
 d="m 1486.5,431.9 -4.5,-10.1 -1.5,0.1 -0.2,4 -3.5,-3.3 1.1,-3.6 2.4,-0.4 1.6,-5.3 -3.4,-1.1 -5,0.1 -5.4,-0.9 -1.2,-4.4 -2.7,-0.4 -4.8,-2.7 -1.2,4.3 4.6,3.4 -3.1,2.4 -0.8,2.3 3.7,1.7 -0.4,3.8 2.6,4.8 1.6,5.2 2.2,0.6 1.7,0.7 0.6,-1.2 2.5,1.3 1.3,-3.5 -0.9,-2.6 5.1,0.2 2.8,3.7 1.5,3.1 0.8,3.2 2,3.3 -1.1,-5.1 2.1,1 -0.5,-4.6 z"
 style="fill:#c1f4ff;fill-rule:evenodd" />
```

I have SVG world map, where I have added some descriptions in a popup info box related to my project. Currently, on the infobox I just have text. I am trying to include some pictures within the pop infobox.

Here I am sharing [the full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEwrwVs3LkyiStTKlNkMSDw_YJbQzsaM/view?usp=sharing) for better understanding. Appreciate your support.

Comment: If you are talking about the default browser tooltip, add the description in a `<title>` tag that is a child of the path.

Comment: It appears you are using (or attempting to use) some sort of tooltip library.  One that uses `data-info` data-name` attributes etc.  But you don't say what that library is.  Please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all wrong and I'm not very sure what are you asking. Take a look at the following example and tell me if this is what you need:

```html
<svg viewbox = "1450 400 50 50">
  <clipPath id="Bangladesh">   

<path d="m 1486.5,431.9 l-4.5,-10.1 -1.5,0.1 -0.2,4 -3.5,-3.3 1.1,-3.6 2.4,-0.4 1.6,-5.3 -3.4,-1.1 -5,0.1 -5.4,-0.9 -1.2,-4.4 -2.7,-0.4 -4.8,-2.7 -1.2,4.3 4.6,3.4 -3.1,2.4 -0.8,2.3 3.7,1.7 -0.4,3.8 2.6,4.8 1.6,5.2 2.2,0.6 1.7,0.7 0.6,-1.2 2.5,1.3 1.3,-3.5 -0.9,-2.6 5.1,0.2 2.8,3.7 1.5,3.1 0.8,3.2 2,3.3 -1.1,-5.1 2.1,1 -0.5,-4.6 z"
 />
    </clipPath>
  
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" x="1450" y="400" height="50" width="50" clip-path="url(#Bangladesh)"/>
</svg>
```

I wasn't able to use your image since it comes from an http (not secure).

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole bunch of code is quite long, and I was unable to add with my post.